# Searching a Matrix Diagonally, Vertically and Horizontally form a point

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm that iterates through an N x N square matrix Diagonally, Vertically and Horizontally from a point whose index is given.

For example, in a 4x4 Matrix, if `[2][1]` are the given index, algorithm should search for the existence of another given element through the indices:

```
[0][1], [1][1], [3][1], // Vertically
[2][0], [2][2], [2][3], // Horizontally
[3][0], [1][2], [0][3], // Diagonally (/)
[1][0], [3][2]          // Diagonally (\)
```

This picture would make it even clear:

[image]

**Note** that the given index (`[2][1]`) is **not included** in the search.

---

I managed to code up a working solution in C++ which is not so efficient:

```
int Check(int arr[][100], int i, int j, int q, int n)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        if ((arr[i][k] == q && k != j) || (arr[k][j] == q && k != i))
            return 1;
    //vertical n horizontal

    if ((i - j) >= 0)
    {
        for (int l = i - j, m = 0; l < n; l++)
            if (arr[l][m++] == q && l != i && (m - 1) != j)
                return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int l = j - i, m = 0; l < n; l++)
            if (arr[m++][l] == q && (m - 1) != i&&l != j)
                return 1;
    }
    //  Diagonal (\)

    int l = i, m = j;
    while (1)
    {
        if (l == 0 || m == n - 1)
            break;
        l--;
        m++;
    }

    if (l == 0)
    {
        while (m >= 0)
            if (arr[l++][m--] == q && (l - 1) != i && (m + 1) != j)
                return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (l < n)
            if (arr[l++][m--] == q && (l - 1) != i && (m + 1) != j)
                return 1;
    }
    //  Diagonal(/)

    return -1;
}
```

`Check()` searches matrix `arr` Diagonally, Vertically and Horizontally from the element `arr[i][j]`. If `q` exists in either of the directions, it returns 1 else, -1.

How can the above be implemented efficiently?

Any code (preferably in C/C++) would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simplify in-loop operations, exclude excessive checks for current cell. Just separate walks before and after the current cell.

```
 //horizontal
 for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
       if (arr[i][k] == q)
           return 1;
 for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++)
       if (arr[i][k] == q)
           return 1;

//main diagonal, case of bottom-left triangle
 dij = i-j;
 if (dij>=0) {
    for (k=0;k<j;k++)
       if (arr[k+dij][k] == q)
           return 1;
    for (k=i+1;k<n;k++)
       if (arr[k][k-dij] == q)
           return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't working for vertical and the other diagonal (other than main diagonal..not sure what its called). You haven't excluded the given `i`,`j` from the search either. Also, in the second loop, why `k = j+1`? (were you checking vertical?)

Comment: I did not write code for vertical and other diagonal, it might be written by analogy.  I DO exclude (i,j). `k = j+1` starts from the right cell

Comment: yeah..you're right, it does exclude. But..i tried splitting that loop into 4 for vertical and horizontal and it appears the single loop is slightly faster..

Comment: It is possible. Modern processors sometimes execute complex loops with smaller cycle count faster than longer simpler loops. Is time for these operations so important for your program? These searchings should be blazing fast for any reasonable matrix size...

Comment: actually, yes. The program is to find solutions to the [N Queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), if you're familiar with it. It's working but takes more than 30 seconds to generate solutions to board size grater than 10. [Here's](http://rextester.com/MBTRC49408) my code if you're interested.

Comment: Seems you for every Q cell check all lines (hor/vert/diag) through this cell. Would it be faster to check only beating previous queens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133885/discussion-between-divins-mathew-and-mbo).